# Website Huge Footer can't seem to reduce size

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem making the footer smaller on this website.

http://leetaxi.webuda.com

after the phone number at the bottom you will see the huge white space, is there any possible way i can reduce this size so its much smaller.

I can't seem to work out what the problem is, i have even though it could be the java scripting at the bottom but it doesn't seem to be that.

If anyone could redirect me on the right path that would be perfect.

Thanks ever so much for your responses.

Comment: Hi, please post your HTML and CSS here in the post, rather than simply linking to your website.

Comment: Hello, i have tried doing this but every time i get the error saying , this code is invalid. so it won't work... but the link is there for anyone to see it for them selves. thanks for your advice!

Comment: Look at your source code. You have 4 `<br>` tags and a `.row` of hidden text after your footer. This is causing the "issue"

Comment: Ok so what do i do to remove the issue, delete the <br> tags? and change .row ?

Comment: The Issue Is fixed. thanks ever so much 3rror404 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably caused by the

```
<br>
```

tags after the footer, and the job of a brake is to create a separate line, so it has the same effect as if you where to hit return on word a few times.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, you were absolutely right.